# What does 'desuspension' mean in the context of homological algebra/graded modules?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, graded-modules

I am familiar with suspensions/reduced supensions/desuspensions etc. in topology, but not in the context of homological algebra and graded modules. What does suspension and desuspension mean in the context of homological algebra/graded rings and modules?

I assume that in Proposition 2.2 of the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf) the authors are referring to the shift functor taking $M_i$ to $M_{i-1}$ as the suspension and the desuspension as the one taking $M_i$ to $M_{i+1}$. But isn't the situation the same for taking $M_i$ to $M_{i-d}$ for any $d\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes? It’s not clear what your question is.

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm just attempting to clarify precisely what is meant by 'suspension' and 'desuspension' in the context of homological algebra/graded modules